# JSON.parse not working inside eclipse plugin development project

Tags: javascript, json, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing an eclipse plugin using **Browser** component. And I'm using **BrowserFunction** to expose some methods to the JS side.

My html is something like below,

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function sayHello() {
    alert("Hello from eclipse plugin javascript !!! ");
};

function alertJson() {
    alert('going to print json');
    alert(JSON.parse('{"apple": 5}'));
};
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>testing</h1>
<button onclick="sayHello();">Click Me</button>
<button onclick="alertJson();">Print JSON</button>
</body>

</html>
```

But only the first alert will pop up as expected. The second one is not popping up.

**Any Idea why the above is not working ?**

NOTE : My intention is to call a Java side function (BrowserFunction which returns a json string using gson) from the JS side and convert that returned json string back to a json object, so that I can manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function alertJson() {
    alert('going to print json');
    alert(JSON.parse('{"apple": 5}'));
};
```

If you are getting a second alert with [object][object] on it. You code is perfectly fine. "[object][object]" is a representation of the value being of type object and not string. JSON.parse as expected is converting your string "{"apple": 5}" into an object. If you wish to check what your function is returning you may do a console.log(JSON.parse('{"apple": 5}')) and check the output inside developer tools hitting F12 on your browser.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not a browser plugin. It's an eclipse plugin. And the second alert will not pop-up. Only the first one appears.

Answer (score 0):

This is a browser issue.
To resolve change web browser settings in menu

> **Window > Web Browser > Internet Explorer**

you can select any other web browser like firefox, chrome[ie], etc. Same code without any modification will work.